# event listener that deletes clicked object

Tags: javascript, arrays, addeventlistener

I have simple table where I want to delete the object that I click on the table.

When I use the code below run into some problems.
When I delete the first object "Nikola" everything works great. However after deleting the first object when I press to delete the second object "Petar" then it deletes the third object "Jovan".

I hope that makes some sense.

```
let table = document.getElementById('tableBody');

let persons = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Nikola' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Petar' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Jovan' },
  { id: 4, name: 'John' },
  { id: 5, name: 'Dare' }
]

makeTable(persons);

function makeTable(list) {
  for (let i = 0; i < persons.length; i++) {
    let row = table.insertRow(-1);
    let cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    let cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    let cell3 = row.insertCell(2);

    let btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.innerHTML = "Delete";

    btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      persons.splice(persons.findIndex(n => n.id == list[i].id), 1);
      e.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement.remove();  
    });

    cell1.innerHTML = list[i].id;
    cell2.innerHTML = list[i].name;
    cell3.appendChild(btn);
  }
}
```

However it  works great using this code for the delete button.

```
btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  let tempPersons = persons.slice(0);
  tempPersons.splice(tempPersons.findIndex(n => n.id == list[i].id), 1);
  persons = tempPersons;
  e.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement.remove();  
});
```

The problem is I don't know why it works good with this code.

Can someone please explain what is going on here. Or tell me where to look for answers.

EDIT:
Sorry if I was not clear enough. I don't need table that works. My table works fine when using the second EventListener. I just want to know WHY it works with the second and not the first EventListener. What is happening that I don't understand. How these things work.

Answer (score 0):

im not sure what you need or what the error, but im trying to figure out what your goal is
so i make this

html

```
<table>
    <tbody id="tableBody">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

script

```
    let table = document.getElementById('tableBody');

    let persons = [
        { id: 1, name: 'Nikola' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Petar' },
        { id: 3, name: 'Jovan' },
        { id: 4, name: 'John' },
        { id: 5, name: 'Dare' }
    ];


    const printTable = () => {
        table.innerHTML = '';
        persons.map( (p, pI) => {
            table.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
                <tr>
                    <td>${pI+1}</td>
                    <td>${p.name}</td>
                    <td><button onclick="del(this, ${p.id})">Delete</button></td>
                </tr>
            `);
        })
    }

    const del = (e, id) => {
        persons = persons.filter( p => p.id !== id);
        printTable();
    }

    printTable();
```

so i make a function to build the table then when delete button is clicked i remove it from arrObj by the id persons then rebuild the table

Answer (score 0):

I made a similar example. It depends if you only want to delete the items from the array or dom only? Or both?

```
let table = document.getElementById('tableBody');

let persons = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Nikola' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Petar' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Jovan' },
  { id: 4, name: 'John' },
  { id: 5, name: 'Dare' }
]

const removePerson = (id) => {
  persons = persons.filter(person => person.id !== id);
  table.innerHTML = '';
  makeTable(persons);
}

const makeTable = (list) => {
  list.forEach((item, i) => {
    const btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.innerHTML = "Delete";
    const row = table.insertRow(i);
    const cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    const cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    const cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    cell1.innerHTML = item.id;
    cell2.innerHTML = item.name;
    cell3.appendChild(btn);

    btn.addEventListener('click', () => removePerson(item.id));    
  })
}

makeTable(persons);
```

This does the same thing as previous answer. First I create the table, then when you delete item from the list it cleans the table and creates according values again. Notice that this is quite heavy operation if you have a lot of data in the table.

Here is a pen https://codepen.io/shnigi/pen/GRogxoY